# Thread safe high performance random generator

Tags: c#, multithreading, random

I need a high performance random number generator that is thread-safe. I need only random bytes in the value type (which is `ulong` for now), not within ranges. I've used the C# built-in `Random` class, but it was kind of slow and not thread-safe.

Later I moved to XORShift functions that actually works very fine, but to achieve thread-safeness I need to put the calculation in `lock`, and that degrades the performance drastically.

What I'm using to generate a random `ulong` is the following:

```
public class Rand
{
    ulong seed = 0;
    object lockObj = new object();

    public Rand()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            seed = (ulong)DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        }
    }

    public Rand(ulong seed)
    {
        this.seed = seed;
    }

    public ulong GetULong()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                ulong t = 0;

                t = seed;
                t ^= t >> 12;
                t ^= t << 25;
                t ^= t >> 27;
                seed = t;

                return t * 0x2545F4914F6CDD1D;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine and fast, but locking makes it take about `1-2us` if it is called from 200 concurrent threads, otherwise calculation finishes under `100ns`.

If I remove locking there is a chance two threads take the same seed and will calculate the same random which is not good for my purposes. If I'm removing the `ulong t` declaration and work directly on the seed then there will be a very little chance to generate the same random for two concurrent calls, but there is also a chance the value will be shifted out from the value range, like `t << 25` will be called many times in a row by different threads without carrying the rotation it will become just simply 0.

I think the proper way would be if there is a shared value that may be changed by any concurrent call and work with that value in the calculation methods, since these values are atomic (at least withing CPU cores) it is not a problem if many calculations are using it in the same time, but that is a problem if this value shifts out from the bitrange.

Is there any good solution to solve this problem? I'd be thankful for any help.

Edit: Ok, I've forgot to mention I have no control over the threads, because async tasks are calling this function, so threads are coming randomly from the threadpool, using thread ID is also a no solution, since there is a chance one specific thread never will call this method again at all, and keeping an instance for that ID is not a good thing.

Comment: It is not, but the xorshift algorithm itself is language agnostic. I could have posted a pseudo-code, or C code, but this is what I'm using and it is technically working, and easily readable, this is why I just copied it. - But You are right anyways, I removed the C tag.

Comment: Giving each thread its own instance of Rand is the obvious approach.  Avoid ThreadLocal if you can.  You just have to make sure to initialize the seed correctly, using another (locked) instance to do that.

Comment: @HansPassant I edited the question, please read the "Edit" at the end.

Comment: Why not just to omit locking and the temp variable `t`? Let threads to shuffle the `seed` concurrently. It could be even more random that it is now.

Comment: Well, you can't avoid ThreadLocal if you want to do it that way.  Having "no control" is very rarely a good way to write performant code.

Comment: @Dmitry I talked about this in my question. The problem is if X different threads are doing seed << 25 exactly in the same time, then seed will be shifted left by 25 X times in a row, and will become 0 very fast. It is not a good way, because them I'm losing the seed, and will produce identical randoms it different threads.

Comment: Technically if instead of shifting I could "rotate" then I guess problem solved. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Maybe if I save the "falling off" bits and add again to the other end of the seed it technically is rotating, and maybe the performance will still be acceptable. Any objections?

Comment: Imo this question is ill-defined

Comment: @HansPassant In async code the concurrent tasks are always assigned to a free thread from the threadpool. There is no point to keep track the current thread ID, because those threads are always used for a a short period of time, new threads may be started, old threads may be killed. If I assign an instance of the Rand() to every thread ID there is a chance instances will never be used again and just sitting in the memory doing nothing, or specific instances will do the main portion of the job. Not a good way to manage this problem.

Comment: Async code is a programming convenience for code that is fundamentally bogged down by I/O overhead.  It is not meant for the kind of code where you count nanoseconds of processor time.  You haven't spent enough time on the basic application, but plenty of good advice to distribute work across dedicated threads is available at this web site.

Comment: @HansPassant This random generator is used right now in a webserver application that can serve over 160k http request/second using purely .net core async call tree. If i let the server create http sessions (stored in cache and db) this number drops to around 90k/sec. If I use this random to generate session tokens then the number drops to 10k/sec. If I remove locking goes back to 80k/sec. It is never a good thing to lock in async methods. Using async semaphore degrades the performance similarly. I'm optimising out every microsec to nanosec level in every method where possible right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without locking and still be threadsafe. Assuming the calculation is very fast (it is) and there is slower code executing around it, it's likely faster to simply recalculate if another thread changes it in between starting the calculation and finishing it. You can do that with an `Interlocked.CompareExchange` spin loop. The only difficulty is that there is no ulong version of that so we have to use an unsafe method to get the equivalent.

```
private static unsafe ulong InterlockedCompareExchange(ref ulong location,
     ulong value, ulong comparand)
{
    fixed (ulong* ptr = &location)
    {
         return (ulong)Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref *(long*)ptr, (long)value, (long)comparand);
    }
 }

public ulong GetULong()
{
    unchecked
    {
       ulong prev = seed;

       ulong t = prev;
       t ^= t >> 12;
       t ^= t << 25;
       t ^= t >> 27;

       while (InterlockedCompareExchange(ref seed, t, prev) != prev)
       {
            prev = seed;
            t = prev;
            t ^= t >> 12;
            t ^= t << 25;
            t ^= t >> 27;
       }

       return t * 0x2545F4914F6CDD1D;
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. I have compared the performance of a similar solution to OP's simple lock-based approach, and using the lock is actually twice as fast. This assuming that all threads are doing nothing else than generating random numbers. But this solution has the merit of preventing frequent thread-switching, and so it may be beneficial in the OP's usage scenario.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, I see similar: if you do nothing but generate random numbers it's slower as there will be a lot of spinning, but as soon as you do anything else inside the loop it gets to be faster than lock().

Comment: @IanMercer Thank you for your idea, seems good, I'll test it for performance and entropy soon.

Comment: @IanMercer: I've just tested it, with 500 concurrent threads generating 100 million randoms in total. Performance was very good, and entropy was perfect. Not a single collision. I think I mark this as the accepted answer, since it fully satisfies the requirements. (Regeneration is not a problem, but using locking is) Thank you!

Comment: Little modification: I've placed the second calculation in do{}while() instead of while(){} to avoid code redundancy, like this I can omit the first calculation completely, didn't affect the performance at all.

Answer (score 7):

Simply create one instance of `Rand` on each thread. Thread-safe, no locking, thus very performant. This can be achieved using the [ThreadStaticAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute?view=net-5.0).

```cs
public static class Rand
{
    [ThreadStatic] private static Rand defaultRand;
    public static Rand Default => defaultRand ??= new Rand();
    // Add extra methods for seeding the static instance...
}

// Then in any thread:
var randomNumber = Rand.Default.GetULong();
```

Comment: While this answer is very useful, thank you very much, I will use this info later, I'm not controlling the threads, because they are async tasks, and coming randomly from the threadpool, so I have no control over the thread id. I should have put this in the question.

Comment: @beatcoder - So you want a fast RNG with some sort of locking?

Comment: @Enigmativity Exactly, the calls should produce lets say "unique" randoms (I know technically it is impossible, but should procude more unique than colliding values), but I'd like to avoid locking withing each call. If there is a way to shift a value left and right with carrying the overflow bits, that would solve the problem.

Comment: @beatcoder, No need to control the threads. I don't understand your objections. My answer is not about thread IDs.

Comment: I'm looking at this solution and I like it, but unfortunately still not solving my issue completely. Very elegant way to assign an instance to individual threads, but I should have each random calculation affect the next calculation, between threads also. The best would be still if I drop the temporary "ulong t" variable, use the seed directly, and instead of shifting use rotating to avoid shifting out. Still thinking about the possible issues. I do perf tests and decide which solution works better. I upvote this answer anyway, because it technically answers the question.

Comment: @beatcoder: Random numbers have no predecessor. What you are demanding makes no sense, or you did not formulate the actual you problem which has additional constraints. Check out also this article about false sharing just in case the performance is not good enough: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/october/net-matters-false-sharing

Comment: @AloisKraus: Since this is a xorshift algorithm it always calculates the next random from the previous state. This is why creating many instances (if they are created with the same seed) will generate identical sequences of randoms. This is why I should not initiate more than one instance and this is why I'm using locking, to avoid collision. While collisions still may happen, I have to keep the chance very low, because checking and generating again is expensive, I don't want to do it too often, this is why I said in the question I want to avoid the lock, not to parallelize the method.

Comment: @AloisKraus: Thank you for that link, very useful information, I'm reading it.

Comment: @beatcoder then use a different seed for each instance `Interlocked.Increment(ref _globalSeed)` and `private static ulong _globalSeed = (ulong) Environment.TickCount;` based your instance start seed on that

Comment: @TheGeneral Not really a good idea, this means I have to keep track the seeds for the instances that are initiated dynamically, pointlessly difficult, and also, expensive.

Comment: @beatcoder yes it does mean keeping an extra 64 bits floating around for each instance and incrementing a global seed when instantiated. However, it also ensures uniqueness. Where your solution will likely suffer from stale values in the cpu cache and the chances of 2 threads getting the exact same value is magnitudes higher

Comment: @TheGeneral: But I already pointed out keeping individual instances for threads is not working, since the threads are randomly coming from the threadpool, and there might be threads calling this method only once, and never anymore, and there might be a few threads that are calling it very frequently. Usage will not be equally distributed between threads, and abandoned instances might float around without any usage. I have to solve with one instance and without locks. A little chance of getting same random is a chance anyways, which is acceptable. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @beatcoder are you seriously worried about the memory overhead associated with storing 8 bytes per thread? Each thread instance allocates 1 MB of RAM just for its stack, so adding 8 more bytes on top of that seems like a drop in the ocean. As for being difficult and expensive, well your improvised solution that is doing unsynchronized math operations has thread-safety implications massively more difficult to understand. How can you say that the rate of collisions of your solution is acceptable, without empirical data from systems with strong and weak memory models?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I'm not (just) worried about the memory overhead, I'm worried about the unbalanced load distribution between the instances. Furthermore having multiple instances with different seed does not make it any more sure there will not be collisions, but entropy might be harmed, because not every random generation call will affect the next random. This can be fixed via using one instance and locking, but then performance will suffer. My tests are showing me this kind of collision is fine. Generating 50-200 colliding randoms out of 100 million in 200-500 threads is ok for me.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Since I've described in the edit of my answer each generated random is tested atomically for uniqueness there is zero chance to colliding randoms will cause an issue, the only question is how many times do I have to call random generation again due to collision. This chance is quite low according to my tests runs, which is in the acceptable range, while performance is 5-6 times higher than with locking. And most importatntly, I'm not locking in async call tree anymore.

Comment: @beatcoder if you have time please read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice) by Igor Ostrovsky. I bet that after reading only the first two paragraphs your confidence about the robustness of your solution will be seriously shaken. Your tests conducted in one machine may not be replicated by tests on another machine with a weaker memory model. By going lock-free you are entering the big black forest of memory models, and there are wolves and dragons there.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Thank you, I will read that, but if you are worried for the values I'm using are getting modified concurrently while working with them is exactly what I want. The only mentionable issue was the returning the same value, which was pointed out by Stanislav, and I worked that around by involving the thread id.

Comment: @beatcoder well, I guess that if *not* being in control of what your program does is exactly what you want, then going lock-free is certainly a good method to achieve this goal!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: What you try to point out is a very valid reason, and I definitely want my program be under complete control, but generating a random value is not something I need to control, since any result that is random is good for me, if there is no such rate of collision that will make my program retrying generating another random excessively. I know I've kind of messed up the xorshift formula and it is not working as intended anymore, but still doing its job. Lockless single instance random was much more important than a little percent of collision, which is handled later anyways.

Answer (score 3):

The less code we execute in the critical section, the faster it will work.
It runs 30-50% faster on my CPU.
You can also use an asynchronous process that will prepare the next collection

```
public sealed class Rand
{
    private ulong seed = 0;
    private readonly object lockObj = new object();
    
    public Rand()
    {
        
        unchecked
        {
            seed = (ulong) DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        }

        _current = 500;
    }

    public Rand(ulong seed)
    {
        this.seed = seed;
    }

    
    private ulong[] _batch = new ulong[501];
    private int _current = -1;

    public ulong GetULong2()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            ulong t = 0;
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                t ^= seed >> 12;
                t ^= t << 25;
                t ^= t >> 27;
                seed = t;
            }
            return t * 0x2545F4914F6CDD1D;
        }
    }


    public ulong GetULong5()
    {
        unchecked
        {

            var t = seed;
            t *= (uint)Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            t ^= t >> 12;
            t ^= t << 25;
            t ^= t >> 27;
            seed = t;
            return t * 0x2545F4914F6CDD1D;
        }
    }
    public ulong GetULong()
    {

        unchecked
        {
            do
            {
            var current = Interlocked.Increment(ref _current);
    
            if (current < 501)
                return _batch[current];

            lock (lockObj)
            {
                if (_current >= 500)
                {
                    ulong t = seed;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 501; i++)
                    {
                        t ^= t >> 12;
                        t ^= t << 25;
                        t ^= t >> 27;
                        var result = t * 0x2545F4914F6CDD1D;
                        _batch[i] = result;

                    }
                    seed = t;

                    _current = -1;
                }
            }
            }while(true);


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This solution uses caching, which is not a bad approach. Thank you for the idea. But not really suitable for me, each calls should run under about the same time. Like this every 500. call will take 500x more time generating a batch, and will need optimisation later, like setting the batch count to the count of concurrent calls. This will take place in a very complex code, and there are already many batchings, I'd avoid more if possible. I upvote this also, because it technically answers the question. Thank you!

Comment: Then look at the GetULong2 method how will performance improve. Multiplication is a long operation, if you remove this code from the critical section it will reduce the execution time

Comment: You are right, I check it out right now. Nice find!

Comment: Well, my original GetULong() method was about 1.4us median on 200 threads, yours GetULong2() was about 1.1us median. Nice improvement, still not enough though. :/

Comment: maybe t ^= seed >> 12; with out copy t = seed; but it could have been done by the compiler, are you building it in the release?

Comment: I think that will not make difference, copying the seed into ulong t had the point of copying the shared value to the stack, therefore using it in the level 1 cache. That little optimisation I think aready happend during compilation. Check my answer what I came up with meanwhile, lowered the calculation time to 100ns level, and seems threadsafe.

Comment: The second `GetULong()` doesn't seem thread-safe to me. One thread may be calling the `_current++` inside the protected region, while another thread may be using the result of the `Interlocked.Increment(ref _current)` in the lock-free region. Both threads could end up using the same `_batch[_current]`.

Comment: I corrected the example, but now it will be slower:)

Comment: @Stanislav: I feel that. Been there, this is why I strictly asked to avoid locking and find a completely different solution to keep the seed changing. It was not a requirement to keep it untouched during the calculation, just to avoid shifting out for the bitrange to get 0. This is fixed with rotation instead of shifting, and you pointed out the concurrent returning issue which is fixed by using the current thread id. Benchmark my answer.

Comment: GetULong5() is 3 times faster than all the others

Comment: The `GetULong5` may be faster, but its behavior is not well defined because of the lack of synchronization. Each thread could generate values based on the seed that itself generated earlier, because the seed may still be cached in the local L1 or L2 cache near the CPU. I have no idea what consequences this may have on the distribution of the generated numbers, or the probability of collisions.

Comment: Yes, there is a possibility of collisions, we need to test the code on different processors. You can add an Interlocked.Exchange(), but this also does not guarantee that there are no problems in synchronization between Cores

Answer (score -2):

Ok [this solution by l33t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64938010/5416434) is a very nice and elegant way to fix the cross-thread issue, and [this solution by Stanislav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64938372/5416434) also a suitable way to prevent on-demand generation by pre-generating and caching batches. Thanks everyone for the ideas.

Meanwhile I changed the bitshift to rotate, this will avoid shifting out the seed to 0, and I could omit the locking. Apparently it works just fine, and with very small latency (200 concurrent threads with about 100-120ns/call)

```
public class Rand
{
    ulong seed = 0;
    object lockObj = new object();

    public Rand()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            seed = (ulong)DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        }
    }

    public Rand(ulong seed)
    {
        this.seed = seed;
    }

    public ulong GetULong()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            seed ^= (seed >> 12) | (seed << (64 - 12));
            seed ^= (seed << 25) | (seed >> (64 - 25));
            seed ^= (seed >> 27) | (seed << (64 - 27));
            seed *= 0x2545F4914F6CDD1D;

            int s = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId % 64;

            return (seed >> s) | (seed << (64 - s));
        }
    }

    // even faster
    public ulong GetULong2()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            seed ^= (seed >> 12) | (seed << (64 - 12));
            seed ^= (seed << 25) | (seed >> (64 - 25));
            seed ^= (seed >> 27) | (seed << (64 - 27));
            ulong r = seed * 0x2545F4914F6CDD1D;
            seed = r;

            int s = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId % 64;

            return (seed >> s) | (seed << (64 - s));
        }
    }

    // better entropy
    public ulong GetULong3()
    {
        unchecked
        {                    
            int s = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId % 12;

            seed ^= (seed >> (12 - s)) | (seed << (64 - (12 - s)));
            seed ^= (seed << (25 - s)) | (seed >> (64 - (25 - s)));
            seed ^= (seed >> (27 - s)) | (seed << (64 - (27 - s)));
            ulong r = seed * 0x2545F4914F6CDD1D;
            seed = r;

            s = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId % 64;

            return (r >> s) | (r << (64 - s));
        }
    }
}
```

While this solution fits my demands the most, I will not mark it as an answer because it does not produce the same randoms as the one in the question, but still produces seemingly unique randoms across all threads, so still might be a solution.

Edit: Ok, after some experimenting `GetULong()` was the fastest, but from 100 million random generations produced more than 23000 colliding values on 200 concurrent threads. Same with `GetULong2()`. Added a little extra for `GetULong3()` method to increase entropy, that produced only about 210 colliding values from 100 million generations on 200 concurrent threads, and only about 50 colliding values from 100 million generations on 500 concurrent threads.

For me this kind of entropy is more than enougn, because they must be unique, so in my application after each generation they are tried to be added to a collection atomically and if there is already one with the same key, then random is called again. 50-200 retry in 100 million events is acceptable even on general random generators, so this is more than enough for me, especially, because it is fast, and can be used tread-safe with only one instance of the random generator.

Thank you everyone for the help, I hope this may help others also.

Comment: if two threads are at the same time at the return point, it will be the same value

Comment: Because of stale values, statistically this wont do what you think it will, and renders the whole question null and void

Comment: @Stanislav: You're right, I think I fixed that with a modification. There is still a little chance to generate the same random, but very little, which is acceptable.

Comment: @TheGeneral: It is true, Stanislav pointed out a real issue. I fixed it with the current edit. Statistically there is still a little chance generating the same random, but very little chance, with is acceptable.

Comment: *"in my application after each generation they are tried to be added to a collection atomically"* <== My guess is that the cost of adding each generated key in a `ConcurrentDictionary` (or other similar storage) should be comparable with the cost of generating the key. Also this mechanism ensures only the uniqueness of the keys that are currently stored in memory. A client may hold a key associated with an old session, that have been abandoned in the server, in which case this client could accidentally hijack the session of another client.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: No that can not happen, the server has a cache and a permanent db storing the session keys, and they have expiry, atomic checking happens in both the cache and the db, if a session is expired, then it is deleted from both the cache and db, and can not be used anymore. If it is regenerated for someone else it can happen only if it is already deleted. There are also other implementations that will not allow session hijacking, because other tokens are also associated with sessions, they need to match.

Comment: So you are hitting the database every time you generate a key, and you think that the bottleneck of your current scheme is the lock that protects a couple of xor/shift operations? Sorry, I don't buy it. I have a fairly slow computer with a 4-core AMD processor, and this machine can generate around 15,000,000 keys per second with your original `Rand` class that uses the `lock`, with any number of threads. I bet that you are optimizing the wrong thing.

Comment: The database is very fast, sometimes faster than a ConcurrentDictionary, and capable of multithreading. While using a lock made all the concurrent connections wait in a queue, getting random token one-by-one, completely eliminating the advantage of the concurrency. A read from the permanent db for checking existing key is about (sometimes less than) 200ns, even with 100 million entries. Not this is the only bottleneck, but definitely one of the biggest bottlenecks.

Comment: Since your database is so fast, does by any chance have a way to generate random numbers by itself? If it does, this should solve your problem quite efficiently and elegantly IMHO.

Comment: "this machine can generate around 15,000,000 keys per second with your original Rand class that uses the lock, with any number of threads" - try the same with 200 concurrent async tcp connections in an await chain with length of 10-15 calls in the stack, locking will change the async operations drastically. While async calls are awaiting to eachother context switches will happen pointlessly just because there is a locking. I've tries async mutexes like SemaphoreSlim, didn't make it much better. Just by changing the random lockless the 10k request/sec jumped back to 80k in my latest benchmark.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I'm using https://github.com/microsoft/FASTER which is quite dumb, but incredibly fast and scales very well. But it is no more than a Key-Value store. Can not generate anything by itself unfortunately. If I used postgresql then I definitely would outsource the unique random to it, but it is slow for this kind of task.

Comment: How many keys are you generating per second on average? My machine caps at 15,000,000 keys per second, so if I reduce the request for keys to a tenth of that (or less), the contention for the lock will become negligible. Most of the time the lock will be acquired immediately without a context switch. The `lock` is very cheap when uncontested. I am certainly not suggesting to replace it with `await SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()`.

Comment: If the context switching is what kills your app's performance, you could consider substituting the `lock` with a [`SpinLock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.spinlock). Generally this is not a great solution, but in your case it may be beneficial.

Comment: Lock generally does Monitor.TryEnter() which is as far as I know does spinlock for a while and then puts the thread in wait state, so it is pointless.

Comment: Weirdly, locking version does around 25 million randoms/sec with 1, 200 or 500 threads, and non-locking version does only about 23 million with 1, 200 or 500 threads. This synthetic benchmark may be misleading, because these are threads calling the random in cycle, while in the application async methods are stacking and this random is called rarely compared to other procedures. It does not reflect why is it important why to avoid locking.

Comment: The `lock` calls the `Monitor.Enter`, not the `Monitor.TryEnter`. I just [tested it](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgzABFATHAwgWAFAG9Nzw+KAFjgFkAKASl3xw3wbgDcBDAJzgBsB7AYwGsAphwC8cAHaCA7nG4AjAFaDeAFyoBuGoy59+ccjwHDq9bXDpm4AXy3XMNjEA===) on sharplab.

Comment: Ok anyways, the application runs significantly faster without the lock in the random, this is fact, so I guess I'm ok with this issue now. I need to continue the job, if I'll know more about this question I'll share it here. Thank you for your help and for testing the code!

Comment: try this one: public ulong GetULong5()
{
unchecked
{

 var t = seed;
 t *= (uint)Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
 t ^= t >> 12;
 t ^= t << 25;
 t ^= t >> 27;
 seed = t;
 return t * 0x2545F4914F6CDD1D;
}
}

Comment: @Stanislav: Thank you, I'll test is soon along with Ian Mercer's solution and report the results.